# Change FormControl value from object (FormGroup) to null and vise versa in Angular 2

Tags: forms, performance, angular, formbuilder, form-control

I have a Form object built with FormBuilder. One of the part of the form needs to be changed dynamically:

```
"Tag": 
  {
     "Id": 10,
     "Name": "Program43",
     "Source": "DSN"
  }
```

I need to change value in "Tag" to null to have:

```
 "Tag": null
```

and later in the form to have something like:

```
"Tag": 
  {
     "Id": null,
     "Name": null,
     "Source": null
  }
```

Any idea of best approach to do it? What method of angular2 is the best to use for this?

Comment: Check out `patchValue` with reactive forms. That would probably be a good option for you.

Comment: `patchValue` doesn't work for my case. I cannot do this: myForm.patchValue({ "Tag": null }) because the value of "Tag" is FormGroup (Object) and not FormControl (string or number)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`AbstractControl#reset`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#reset-anchor) method:

```
const tagGroup = this.FORM.get('Tag');
tagGroup.reset();
console.log(tagGroup.value); // { Id: null, Name: null, Source: null }
```